# Resize Image after upload, not working?

Tags: php, image-processing

Okay,

So I have a PHP file that uploads a image to my server. After uploading, I want to resize the image to a 100X100 file. Below is my code that doesn't work.

Please help!

```
<?php
include 'resize.image.class.php';

$get_username = "usernamehere";
$new_id = "19";

$uploadDir = "./../users/$get_username/pictures/";
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadFile = $file;
$newName = $uploadDir . $new_id . $uploadFile;
$file_size = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {

    $image = new Resize_Image;
    $image->new_width = 100;
    $image->new_height = 100;
    $image->image_to_resize = "./../users/$get_username/pictures/$new_id.jpg"; // Full Path to the file
    $image->ratio = true; 
    $image->new_image_name = "$new_id";
    $image->save_folder = "./../users/$get_username/pictures/thumbnails/";
    $process = $image->resize();

}

?>
```

It's a simplified version. However, when I run the resize code separately, the code works. Thoughts?

Thanks again!

Comment: Are there any errors? What is resize.image.class.php?

Comment: The only error: The file doesn't exist.

Comment: I got the class from here: http://www.bitrepository.com/web-programming/php/resizing-an-image.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly specifying the 'source' file name. The source file must be accessed by the temp_name thing. So, this line in your code is faulty:

```
$image->image_to_resize = "./../users/$get_username/pictures/$new_id.jpg";
```

Instead, do this:

```
$image->image_to_resize = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: Yes, either that or copy/move the temporary uploaded file to `"./../users/$get_username/pictures/$new_id.jpg";` before you run the resizing.  If you don't move it, it won't be available full size for use later.